# Send email with generated PDF as attachment?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itext, html-email, email-attachments

I am using the code below to generate a PDF and save it to a location. Would it be possible to have this sent out as an email with the generated PDF attached? I am assuming the Email coding would need to be done in HTML? because it will be on a webserver. Is this possible?

```
    Dim Doc1 As New Document
    Dim path As String = "\\Server\Folder" + Session("Username") + "\"
    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) Then

        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
    End If
    Dim myUniqueFileName = String.Format("{0}.pdf", random)
    Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(Doc1, New FileStream(path & myUniqueFileName, FileMode.Create))
    ' Dim ev As New itsEvents
    ' pdfWrite.PageEvent = ev

    Doc1.Open()
    Dim test As String
    test = Session("PDF")
    Dim imagepath As String = Server.MapPath(".") & "/images/Header.png"
    Dim image As iTextSharp.text.Image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagepath)
    image.ScalePercent(70.0F)
    ' image.SetAbsolutePosition(36.0F, 36.0F)
    Doc1.Add(image)
    Doc1.Add(New Paragraph(test))

    Doc1.Close()
```

Comment: Have you looked into the `System.Net.Mail` namespace?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.Mail.aspx

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure how I would grab that attachment?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx There are constructors that take a string, and some that take a stream. You should be able to find one that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
' Create the mail message
Dim mail As New MailMessage()

' Set the addresses
mail.From = New MailAddress("me@mycompany.com")
mail.To.Add("you@yourcompany.com")

' Set the content
mail.Subject = "This is an email"
mail.Body = "this content is in the body"

' Get some binary data
Dim data As Byte() = GetData()

' Save the data to a memory stream
Dim ms As New MemoryStream(data)

' Create the attachment from a stream. Be sure to name the data with a file and 
' media type that is respective of the data
mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(ms, "example.txt", "text/plain"))

' Send the message
Dim smtp As New SmtpClient("127.0.0.1")
smtp.Send(mail)

Function GetData() As Byte()
    ' This is where you will load your data from disk or database, etc.
    Dim s As String = "this is some text"
    Dim data As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s)
    Return data
End Function 'GetData
```

Comment: In the following code line, how would I point to the attachment? Say if its on \\Server1\Attachments\? mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(ms, "example.txt", "text/plain"))